# Position of vote buttons with long questions/answers

Tags: discussion, voting

When I was reading a question with a long description, I wanted to upvote it, but due to the long text, I had to scroll all the way up again. At this point I was torn between scrolling up (to upvote the question) and scrolling down to take a look at the answers.

My lazy side told me to not bother with the upvote despite it being a good question, and my curiosity to see the answers won. By the time I had read the answers, I had forgotten that I wanted to upvote the question and closed the browser tab. This means that a good question missed out on an upvote.

I guess the same applies to answers with long text. If I read through the answer and decide that it's a good answer, the additional work of having to scroll up to upvote the answer is keeping me from upvoting.

Maybe I'm just lazy, but wouldn't it be better to keep the up/down vote buttons in view when scrolling up and down on the page? At least as long as part of the question is in view? I'm pretty sure many of the longer questions and answers are missing out on votes due to this. Wouldn't it make sense to *float* the buttons next to the question or answer?

Comment: It's not taking a lot of time to quickly scroll up, upvote and then read the answers but i agree with you that it can impact the upvotes if many users are as lazy as you ;-)

Comment: it looks like this is happening in an a/b test now.

Comment: Similar question here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35041/move-the-vote-button/254795#

Comment: A/B test here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please?cb=1

Answer (score 6):

> wouldn't it be better to keep the up/down vote buttons in view when scrolling up and down on the page?

No. Scrolling elements in browsers are annoying and hard to do good.

Comment: Do you mean floating elements? Cause the OP is not sugestion any more scroll-bars. What he seems to suggest is making the vote-arrows and count(s) not stay anchored to the top of the post, but instead to the topmost-part of the post which can be seen.

Comment: Yes, I mean the floating elements that try to stay in view while scrolling.

Comment: They would be nice, if they fully succeeded (at least used judiciously). Fact is, they lag a bit and move in spurts and jumps, which negates their appeal completely.

Comment: Yes, I meant something like that. I'm a bit shocked by the answer, to be honest. "Annoying" is pretty subjective - why is it annoying if it serves a good purpose? Secondly, should we settle for "hard to do good"? Before Stackoverflow came along, web-based Q&A also was "hard to do good".

Comment: @nwinkler given the votes people agree with my opinion. Please link me to one site where you think this feature is implemented well. It is associated with crappy websites full of ads, I don't think it would fit on SO.

Comment: I'm not debating that. The question is whether we should settle for this. Just because no other site does it well at the moment, does that mean that it can't be done?

Comment: @nwinkler I'm sure there is a way to make it work, but it's solving a problem I personally never encountered. What resolution and scroll speed do you use? I think the developers' time can better be put in more important issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my the voting buttons should be on the boron to make sure the voters are voting for the question/answer, not the person

Comment: Actually, the bottom of a post is exactly where the username appears. It is not seen at the top of a long post.